# Repeat control bound to array of arrays returning string in the repeat collection

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to display a subset of a view in a repeat control by getting a NotesViewEntryCollection and then looping through this collection to build an array for which each value in the array contains an array corresponding to the column values in the entry.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var view:NotesView = database.getView("CatalogEntries");
            var entryColl:NotesViewEntryCollection = view.getAllEntriesByKey(compositeData.catalog, true);
            if (entryColl.getCount() == 0) return ["empty"];
            var entries = [];
            var columnVals = [];
            var entry:NotesViewEntry = entryColl.getFirstEntry();
            do {
                columnVals = [];
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[0]);
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[1]);
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[2]);
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[3]);
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[4]);
                columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[5]);
                entries.push(columnVals);
                entry = entryColl.getNextEntry(entry);
            } while(!(entry == null))
            return entries;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:rowData[rowIndex][0]}"></xp:text>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

But I am getting an error at this line:
`<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:rowData[rowIndex][0]}"></xp:text>`

The error is:

> Unknown member '0' in Java class 'java.lang.String'

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that this can - no should! - be simplified. The basic idea is that you can either feed a Domino view datasource or your entire `NotesViewEntryCollection` object *as it is* into your `repeat` object. This way you end up with `rowData` representing a single `NotesViewEntry` object. Your `computedField` value can then directly reference any element from the entry's `columnValues` Vector. This way you don't even need to bother recycling any objects:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="myView" viewName="CatalogEntries" keys=compositeData.catalog keysExactMatch="true">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" value="#{myView}">
        <xp:panel id="pnInner">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    if(rowData){
                        return rowData.getColumnValues()[0].toString();
                    }else{
                        return "empty";
                    }}]]>
                </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

Filtering of your view data is done at the datasource level.

Comment: I agree completely with Lothar. dominoView with `keys` property set is doing pretty much what you're doing, but using a ViewNavigator and restricting the amount of entries data is collected from at runtime for better performance, plus recycling both view entries and the view entry values (which could include Date/Times, which are not automatically recycled when recycling the ViewEntry). Only manually iterate the ViewEntries when absolutely required. `getColumnValues()` has to extract all column values, so even if you only want one column, you actually have to get them all, so no saving there.

Comment: Totally agree with this approach. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your push method you do not pass in the array index.

```
columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues()[0]);
```

should be

```
columnVals.push(entry.getColumnValues());
```

Howard

Comment: And, be sure to recycle as you loop through the Notes view!